# Total Server Memory and Target Server memory Value same

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, memory

Can anyone help me what does this indicate:

From the MSDN forums thread [Total Server Memory VS Target Server Memory made me crazy](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1e51965d-fbb1-4f73-b977-5284516b3d45/total-server-memory-vs-target-server-memory-made-me-crazy) answer by Jonathan Kehayias:

> If Total Server Memory is less than Target Server Memory it can be a
>   sign of memory pressure

But in my case the values are same:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in my case the values are same :

You cannot and should not come to conclusion that SQL Server is facing memory pressure by just looking at one perfmon counter, this is just not correct. You have to rely on other perfmon counters which I am sure you are aware.

Now for your question, since both are same this means the SQL Server memory requirement is balanced as of now and its quite likely that SQL Server is not facing memory pressure. In most cases I have seen that on steady system target and total server memory are equal and I have always found out that when they are same it means currently there is no memory pressure.

Comment: Thanks Shanky ,thanks for the responses each time. I am trying to understand SQL Server Memory correct and sometime I am going crazy to understand things properly. Your responses help me so much. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Shanky,sorry for extra question,Follow up on your response :                   As for heading question NO, memory for SSIS does not comes from buffer pool in any instance of SQL Server – Shanky Jul 28 '15 at 4:15 same is the case with SSRS,SSAS too...are they out of SQL Server Maximum Memory ? Can you please tell me what else are out of SQL Server Max Memory ? Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what version of SQL Server we are taking. Yes for SSIS, SSAS and SSRS the memory comes outside from buffer pool. Buffer pool is mainly for satisfying database engine requests

Comment: Shanky mine is SQL Server 2008 R2,Thanks again lot.